# If X1 is a random variable with Normal[0, 1] distribution, then what is the distribution of X1 + X1?

Tags: probability

I thought that this is the same as finding the distribution of $X1 + X2$ in which $X2$ also follows $Normal[0, 1]$. If that were the case, the answer would simply be $Normal[0, \sqrt{2}]$. But apparently, this is not the case. I believe the gist of this problem is what $X1 + X1$ distribution exactly means.

Comment: Start with definition of CDF of a r.v.

Comment: Hi @popping900, I believe X1 + X1 means taking 2 independent random samples from X1? If you say X1 + X1 = 2 X2, this implies that you take 1 random sample from X1 and then multiply it by 2?

Comment: Hi @popping900, even if $X1 + X1 = 2 X1$, $2X1$ should ~ N(0, 2) instead.